# XCM FailedToTransactAsset, maybe xcm version error?

Tags: xcm

We have been attempting an xcm reserve asset transfer of ROC (native token) from Rococo to our parachain. It fails with a cryptic FailedToTransactAsset.
It works on our local testnet just fine. The only difference I can spot is that in our local tests, we set the SafeXcmVersion to 1 via force_default_xcm_version.
Could this be a xcm version issue? If yes, then can we have the relay chain use xcm v1 for our parachain perhaps with force_xcm_version which is a root call. Will this have to be done on Kusama as well?

Comment: There is too little information here. Please state what reserve chain you are attempting to use, the full XCM you are sending, what chain you are sending from, what chain you expect to be credited, the XCM config on the reserve chain (unless it is one of those in the Polkadot/Cumulus codebase), the XCM config of the final destination chain.

Comment: Apologies for the missing information.
The issue has been resolved.
Will keep this in mind next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was not enough funds were being sent to cover costs.

Thank you.

Comment: Was it clear that this was the case? Specific error messages are key to usability.